# How do lethal martial arts techniques work?

Tags: theory

There are several lethal techniques I learned in my self defense class. One is a chop to the back of the neck, another is slamming the head on the floor. What makes the lethal techniques lethal? Why do the kill a human being? Is there a commonality between them that makes them fatal? I already have a whole bunch of them, I am not asking for "how to do them" or "what are they." I would like a theoretical knowledge of them, like what is the principle or science behind why they are lethal.

Comment: These techniques *could* be lethal, not *are* lethal (this is the substantive part of  [Steve's answer](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/13451/70)). Slamming the opponent's head on the floor might be lethal the first time you do it, or the 100th, or maybe not at all. The human body is remarkably resilient, pretty much none of the "lethal" strikes are truly/instantly lethal without several contributing factors occurring at the same time as the strike.

Comment: Let's add a few: There are normally three ways you can send someone to the morgue without a weapon. You can cut off air or blood supply to the brain (by crushing the windpipe or choking, putting pressure on the vagus nerve), or you can slam the back of the head into a hard surface (you mentioned that).

Comment: Or, disrupt their chi so the guy is chi-less. Luckily, this takes practice, which bad guys usually don't have patience for.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, "lethal" techniques are like "lethal" injuries in that sometimes they are and sometimes they aren't depending on the target, your execution, and random factors. Secondly, martial arts have a bad habit of labeling certain techniques as "dangerous" or "deadly" without any real basis whether it's spreading mythical techniques like "smashing the nose into the brain", discussing techniques that could be deadly, but probably not immediately or reliably like crushing the windpipe with a strike or hitting the solar plexus and causing whole-body paralysis, or simply over-estimating the danger like "12 to 6" elbows to the head in MMA.

Past that, the commonality of "lethal" techniques is basically more or less what you'd expect, that they interrupt a vital process in the body, although they tend to do it by different methods. A sharp blow to the chest can stop the heart (but you have to hit it just right, in between beats). A sharp blow to the solar plexus can cause a storm in the nerves that causes whole-body paralysis, including inability to breathe (but more often only temporarily "knocks the breath out of you"). A sharp blow to the back of the neck can cause spinal cord issues that will paralyze the heart and lungs or a blood clot that will migrate into the brain and cause a stroke. Blows to the temple similarly can cause blood clots that will migrate into the brain.  A sharp blow to the inside of the thigh can cause the blood clot. Crushing the trachea can make it impossible to breathe without a tracheotomy.  Sufficient cranial trauma can create pressure build-up in the brain or destroy parts of the brain that govern autonomic things like breathing and having the heart beat.

And lastly, any sufficiently traumatic attack (say, the classic "monkey seizes the grapes" where you rip off the testicles with an Eagle Claw attack) can cause blood loss and shock that can lead to death.

So, long story short, they generally aren't all that lethal, they don't all share something in common, and when they do, it's the same as any other traumatic injury in that it's enough damage to cause the body to shut down or side effects that lead to death.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't expect you will be able to apply any of these moves in a real self-defense scenario. Why? Because you never trained to apply them with full force under similar levels of stress, ie. your training stimulus was very different from the situation you will find yourself in. And the brain is particularly bad at transferring stuff learned in a different situation when under stress.

That said, the body is pretty well built to protect any vital organs and areas.

*Can* you kill a person by chopping their neck? Yes. But the force needed to actually *kill* a healthy person is comparable to hitting full-force with a baseball bat. You would need to cause a significant trauma to the spine and/or blood vessels or force the brain into a double bounce (forward backward) and thereby cause enough swelling to impede blood flow or cause blood vessels to pop. Same with smashing a head on the floor. Even a broken skull is not necessarily lethal, those things may render a person *unconscious* but it is quite a different story to *kill* them. Hits to the temple and the neck are simply more *likely* to induce death because of how they tend to induce severe head trauma due to how they move the head and thus the brain inside of it. It still takes time before they actually die because of it.

Most "deadly" techniques depend on delivering an insane amount of force directly to or nearby the brain. They are not reliable by any stretch. Other supposedly deadly attacks that try to trigger nerves are even less reliable as the timing and amount of accuracy needed to have them be so devastating that the shock can or comes close to killing is not realistically achievable in a real fight with a live, moving, resisting opponent.

Causing blood clots that cause a stroke in vital organs is a myth, won't happen (aside from anecdotal, very rare cases). You'd need a target that already suffers under health conditions and aim perfectly, so nothing you can or should train for.

Reliable are low-effort high-damage moves like poking *through* the eyeballs up (directly into the frontal cortex), snapping the neck, or breaking the trachea. Two directly severe the central nervous system, one the breathing. All have in common that the target is directly accessible for physical manipulation, from the outside. All have in common that it is highly improbable up to nigh impossible to pull them off against a resisting opponent who has the attention directed towards you. Simply because not only the body is built to protect vital areas, it also has *reflexes* that will help in doing so through movement. Whenever something is coming towards the eyes/trachea *at speed*, people will react with turning the head and tucking the chin. It's natural, involuntary.

Long story short, there *are* things all "lethal" techniques have in common:

1. There is no way to train them properly, so you will not be able to apply them in any serious encounter and much more likely just freeze as you never trained for this high-stress, full-power scenario. If you trained stuff in this scenario, it is not lethal techniques, and you will automatically resort to this stuff.
2. As if that wasn't bad enough, the few that would work through direct physical manipulation of vital points would be exceedingly *hard* to apply as you would have to *get to them despite movement, resistance, and very fast involuntary, reflexive defense*.
3. "Lethal" techniques are mostly about techniques that have a high percentage of *incapacitating* an opponent with a slight chance of leading to their death *eventually*. This is why they are not trained full-force and taken out of any curriculum aiming at the ability to apply techniques.

Besides obvious legal problems, this is why any serious self-defense instructor I ever worked with never trained any supposedly lethal technique. If you *want* to kill a person without the use of a weapon, you smack their head and/or hit deep into the abdomen many, many times so that internal injuries (head trauma or internal bleedings due to ripped tissue) eventually lead to death, long *after* they are rendered unconscious. This involves extreme levels of readiness to be violent and recklessness. It is way beyond martial arts or the goal of self-defense, which is to *avoid, mitigate, or incapacitate* a threat. There is no human kill switch.

Comment: I beg to differ on this.  There is a human kill switch.  It's the internal carotid artery.  It's about 2" inside the neck but there is nothing much in the way of it to stop you from digging a finger in and messing it up.  I don't care if you call it a pressure point or not but it's not at all safe to press on.

Comment: @HuwEvans But that's the point. Are there areas that are lethal to mess with? Certainly. Are they easy to access **and** certain to work *if you try against resistance*?  No, not at all. Saying that there isn't much to stop you digging is kind of unrealistic. There isn't if there isn't resistance, movement, and tension, true. How realistic is it to hit a given point 2" in in any realistic, live scenario?

Comment: Klocking.  It's as easy as punching to the face.  You wouldn't gently reach for it.  you would hit it hard with 2 fingers.

Comment: @HuwEvans You would certainly try. The chance that hitting a small area close to the head with two fingers in the correct angle with sufficient force works against a moving, resisting human being still is mind-boggingly low, even for very proficient martial artists against an average street thug. It's not like hitting the face at all. It's like hitting the temple with your first two knuckles at an orthogonal angle. Give your partner an integral helmet, mark a small spot with tape, and have a go at full speed and resistance, with them going all out as well. You think you would hit this spot?

Comment: Any striker that trains without gloves trains this level of accuracy. It's not easy for a beginner, but over time it becomes more realistic.

Comment: @HuwEvans As I said: Have you ever tested this in a full-speed, full-force sparring (obviously with some protective gear)? If not, this is mere conjecture.

Comment: The neck, no. (Protective gear for this is expensive). Pretty much any other part of the body, yes of course.

Answer (score 2):

The question is: *What makes a martial arts technique considered "lethal" by martial arts?*

My answer to this question is very simple: **Intention.**

If I punch someone in the face, is that a lethal technique? There are times when punching someone in the face has caused death. The brain gets a concussion, and there's bleeding in the brain which causes pressure to build up. That could cause a person to die as much as 24 hours later.

Or perhaps I punch them in the face so hard that it snaps the guy's neck. That could result in death.

Or, more realistically and actually much more common, if I punch someone and knock them out or cause them to lose their balance, they could fall and land on their head, and that could very easily kill them.

So is punching someone in the face considered a lethal technique in martial arts? No. Because, that isn't the **intention**. I don't intend to kill someone by punching them in the face. And if I did want to kill someone, there are techniques I could choose which have a higher chance of doing so.

An example of a technique that is considered lethal within martial arts or by martial artists is something like grabbing the head and twisting to break the neck. The intention is to snap the neck, and that would be lethal if successful.

The knife-hand chop technique to the back of the neck, if intended to break the neck, would be considered a lethal technique. It's actually not so easy to break neck bones, by the way, and the knife-hand chop rarely actually does break the neck bones themselves. Instead, the knife-hand chop to the back of the neck usually results in the head recoiling back which is what can either snap the bones of the neck, tear the spinal nerves, or cause tearing of the arteries of the neck. So those could potentially cause death. It would need to be extremely quick and powerful. Not likely, but possible.

Most knife-hand chops to the back of the neck just result in a KO. That's because the head jolts backwards, and that causes a KO. And again, knocking someone out can result in death if the person falls and hits their head on the ground or something.

Striking the front of the neck is considered a lethal technique in martial arts, too. The intention is to collapse the throat. That can certainly result in death. It might require quick medical intervention to allow a person to breathe again, through a tube.

Some martial arts consider it a lethal technique to kick the testicles. And there have been examples of people dying as a result of testicles being smashed. It's possible, although unlikely. This is an example of a case where martial arts **folklore is wrong or highly exaggerated**. Kicking the testicles almost never should result in death, although the recipients of the kick may feel otherwise. Haha.

There are many other cases where martial arts folklore says that some technique is lethal, but in reality it almost never is. Clapping on the ears, poking out eyes, punching arm pits, kicking testicles, and so on are examples of this. Those hurt a lot, though! And they could cause irreparable damage, like poking out the eyes or losing your hearing. But they don't cause death.

Perhaps in the past, someone was observed dying after getting hit with one of these techniques. And so since it occurred *after* it, then some might have concluded that it was caused *by* it. That's a logical fallacy, and something people are guilty of quite often.

Like you can watch someone getting into a fight, and it ends after a guy gets knocked out. That guy goes home and dies before the day is up. Since this occurred hundreds of years ago, people are unfamiliar with concussions and the dangers of bleeding on the brain as a result. So they think back to the fight and try to figure out what technique caused his death. They overlook the knock-out and instead focus on maybe some secret dim-mak death strike that they saw his opponent doing. It might have been a finger tip strike to the armpit. And so now word spreads that attacking the armpit is a lethal technique. When in fact, it was the concussion as a result of the knock-out which caused the guy's death. But they didn't have modern medical science to know that was what really happened.

So a lot of what's considered "lethal" in martial arts is the result of **folklore**.

Legally, there's another answer: **Consequences.**

Legally, the intention does also matter, but it's the consequences of actions that matter the most. So if what you did results in death, legally you're in trouble. It doesn't matter whether your intent was not lethal. What matters most is what actually happened as a result of what you did.

Like in the case of punching to the face, you probably didn't intend for it to be lethal. But your opponent fell down, smashed his head on the ground, and died later on as a result. So you caused his death. Legally, you're in deep trouble.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But isn't the point of a so-called lethal technique to supposedly give a technical solution to the problem of how to kill a human being?

Comment: @ Philip I suppose that there is no such thing as a "lethal" technique without a weapon (because "lethal" moves require a lot more than technicality to be lethal). And some people are physiologically more prone to survive, so...

Comment: @VesperX That is kind of point, ie that everyone talking about lethal martial arts techniques is basically delusional as this very term is oxymoronic. This should be highlighted when talking about this IMHO.

Comment: I did mention a couple really, truly lethal non-weapon techniques in my answer, though. They are done with the intention of killing, and they actually do kill, realistically. (Neck twist was one, the other was collapsing the trachea.) But, are there many of those? Meh. No. And dim-mak is bs, so excluding all of those "death point" techniques, you're left with just a small number of things you can do with your bare hands. I didn't also mention that you could easily slam someone's head against a hard object by way of a throw or just grabbing someone's head and slamming it against a brick wall.

Comment: But personally, it doesn't matter to me that there aren't that many lethal techniques. My answer was more concerned with defining them rather than enumerating them.